# Addressing specific named dataset columns

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, dataset

So, recently I started working with datasets, using jupyter notebook. And I've been wondering, how can I address columns or rows, if I don't know their names? I know it should be something like Data["name"], but I'm not sure if it's possible to do any different way? I've been trying to do it like you would in Python, but it always ends up in error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7005df7eac4b> in <module>
      2 data = list(frame['data'])
      3 target = (frame['target'])
----> 4 wine_frame = pd.DataFrame(frame['data':3])
      5 wine_frame['target'] = frame['target':3]
      6 sns.pairplot(wine_frame, hue='target')

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Comment: maybe you can read this if my answer is helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]

Answer (score 0):

Didnt know column name is not a nice thing to do,Especially if you will used it for data analyst,pandas have a lot built in function.You can use.In jupyter notebook you can assigned variabel to keep an value

```
Value = df.columns
```

You can find many thing in google like this one
[enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-column-names-in-pandas-dataframe/)